# Ruby on Rails - Completed 500 internal error on f.label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, label

**EDIT**

**Here's the project on GitHub: https://github.com/lionelrudaz/myteam2**

---

I'm making my first application in Ruby on Rails by using the template on Railsapp (Twitter Bootstrap, Devise and CanCan).

I've also made the necessary steps to publish my app to Heroku.

Everything went fine so far, first publication on Heroku was alright, until I restarted the server on my MacBook Pro.

Now I get always the default error page with message "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

In the terminal, I get:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-01 19:19:21 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
     User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
     Club Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clubs".* FROM "clubs" ORDER BY "clubs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (23.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 190ms
```

Since I don't know how to disable the error page to get a real stack trace, I've started to remove lines of code by lines of code to find which line isn't working. Actually, it looks like the f.label instructions aren't working anymore. I know they did, I've used my app for a long time.

Here's my home_controller.rb file

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @club = Club.last
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h3>Home</h3>

<%= debug @club %>

<%= form_for @club do |f| %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= RUBY_VERSION %>
    <%= Rails.version %>
    <%= f.label :name, :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

 <% end %>

 <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <p>User: <%=link_to user.name, user %></p>
 <% end %>
```

The error is fired when I change

```
 <%= f.label :name, :name %>
```

to

```
 <%= f.label :name %>
```

I updated my app on Heroku so you can check the debug: http://myteam2.herokuapp.com/

I don't know what's wrong, it's so basic that I feel so dumb.

When I was investigating, I've remarked that the second argument of f.label must be a String. It's impossible to use the t() method to change the text of the email from a i18n file.

I can't go ahead with my application and feel really frustrated. My Google researches haven't been successful.

Let me know if you need more information.

Cheers,

Comment: If you are starting the server locally in development mode you should get an error page with backtrace.  If you are using development mode, maybe post the contents of your config/development.rb file (with any sensitive information removed).

Comment: Hello dear Wizard of Ogz, thanks for your answer. Here's the file: https://github.com/lionelrudaz/myteam2/blob/master/config/environments/development.rb. Hope this helps. Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lionel, you should seen an error message when you are running your project locally with the development environment.

I cloned your project and after a little setup I ran `rails s` to start the project with the default development environment.  The home page loaded fine, but clicking "Login" to go to /users/sign_in showed the following error:

## Error:

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s157/sh/078d0a12-73b1-4eb7-9430-55b916f19ef7/12c0cbb7b7254e5c02bb7ff0f0c4aa3f

The error indicates that a problem exists within config/locales/users.en.yml, that a Hash was expected, but none was returned.

Currently config/locales/users.en.yml is a blank file.

## Fix:

You can either delete that file.  Do this if you never plan on using it.

OR

add content so that parsing the file returns data in the form of a Hash.  Simply add `en:` to the top of config/locales/users.en.yml.  Do this if you plan on entering translation data in the future.

## Other:

It seems like you are developing your application on Heroku.  From my experience this will be difficult.  It is much easier to develop locally adding features and fixing bugs.  Then deploy to Heroku once your app is in a stable state.  You can even set up a separate staging server on Heroku so you can test your changes before deploying to your production server.

Using the heroku gem you can run `heroku logs --tail` to monitor output from your application.  If you had not been using that it may have helped solve your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Wizard of Ogz! I can't test it right now, but will definitely try when I'm back at home. I knew it was a silly mistake, this is insane! Quick question: how can I remove this "Sorry, something went wrong message", [screenshot](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/b3d39e92-839a-4eff-bc3e-cfccf11fd72a/bb0d18a4e982ab5fe492ee5865fa6915), and get the stack trace like on your screenshot? Thanks in advance

Comment: @lionel I think maybe you are running your server in production mode locally.  What command are you using to start your server?  `rails s` or `rails s -e development` should start in development environment so you would see a backtrace.

Comment: Thanks mate, solution works great! But changing the way I launch the server doesn't have any effects. Nevermind, I'll stumble upon for a solution. Cheers

Comment: @lionel make sure this line is still in your config/environments/development.rb:  `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

Comment: It's here. I figure out that there's a 500.html page in the public folder which is called when I have this kind of error. Just don't know where to disable the redirection to this file when I get errors. I will find a solution eventually. Thanks for your help Wizard, I highly appreciate. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing using label with and without a form builder.

When you use `label` inside of `form_tag`, it takes two parameters: the first is the name of the parameter required to connect the label to the appropriate text field, and the second is the actual label text.

However, when you use `form_for @whatever do |f|`, the label's first parameter is automatically known, since you do `f.label :name`, and f knows what name is, and what `f.text_field` will generate, and does all the nastiness for you.

This is often not clear in the Rails documentation, but as a rule you can eliminate the first parameter of the form helper methods when you're doing them from an associated model using `form_for`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer. I know, that's why I don't understand why <%= f.label :name %> doesn't work. It worked fine for weeks and then, I don't know why, it doesn't work anymore. What can I send you to give you more inputs?